# Parameterized Junit class - How to send an ArrayList as a parameter to a method()

Tags: java, junit4, junit5

Consider the below code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.assertj.core.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class StackFrustratedCoderTest {
    private List<Integer> input;
    private Integer expected;
    private ItcStackFrustrated itcStack;

    public StackFrustratedCoderTest(List<Integer> array, Integer expected){
        this.input = array;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Before
    public void init(){
        itcStack = new ItcStackFrustrated();
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public Collection parameterInput(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{1,7,2,2,4,4}, 11}});
    }

    @Test
    public void testFrustatedCoder(){
        assertEquals(this.expected, itcStack.check(this.input));
    }
}
```

Consider the method itcStack.check() is a function to be tested and as an argument, it needs ArrayList variable.

How to code it in the below method:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
        public Collection parameterInput(){
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{1,7,2,2,4,4}, 11}});
        }
```

The above code shows compilation error. {1,7,2,2,4,4} is an int array but I need ArrayList. Any suggestions are appreciated.

And also, if any article can be provided where its explained how do the Parameterized class functions internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here:

```
{1,7,2,2,4,4}
```

is a literal that would create an array of int.

Simply go:

```
Arrays.asList(1, 7, 2, ...);
```

instead.

**EDIT**

We can do that in this way.

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,7,2,2,4,4};
return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{Arrays.asList(array), 11}});
```